# sourcelinks and fogbugz

Tags: fogbugz

I just installed this:
http://www.wholetomato.com/products/sourcelinks/FogBugzBundle.asp
but I don;t seem to be getting any of the functionality in my msdev.  I am using 2008 professional.

Anyone have any experience with this tool?  it does not seem to work for me at all.  I never get the login dialog.

Comment: Tim,

I think you had an email conversation with us about this right?  If you figure out what went wrong can you post here?

Comment: Michael, I will certainly post it.  The support staff at whole tomato logged it as a defect I think.  I have not heard anything for a couple days.  Thee symptoms are perplexing.  I might try to install it on another machine just to see if I can get it to work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After about a week the Whole Tomato team gave me a solution that worked perfectly.  Thanks for the support Mark, etc.

the answer is below

> After doing some research, I came
> across this page:
>
> http://www.mztools.com/articles/2007/MZ2007009.aspx
>
> that lists several possibilities why
> it might not be showing up in the
> add-in manager.  One of them is:
>
> "There is a reported problem that
> happens when MSXML 6.0 is not
> installed correctly. In this case the
> Add-In Manager doesn't show any
> XML-based add-in (using an .AddIn file
> for registration). It shows only
> registry-based add-ins. So, if the
> Add-In Manager is empty when it should
> show several installed add-ins (not
> only yours), try reinstalling MSXML
> 6.0."
>
> You might try reinstalling XSXML 6.0,
> and see if that helps.  Download link
> is here:
>
> http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=993c0bcf-3bcf-4009-be21-27e85e1857b1&displaylang=en
>
> I'd certainly try that before
> reinstalling VS2008.